# How to save one to one relations with Gorm?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

How do I save user's address relation with Gorm and Postgres?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
)

var (
    pgUri = "postgres://postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable"
)

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Email   string
    Address Address
}

type Address struct {
    gorm.Model
    Street  string
    City    string
    Country string
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", pgUri)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to connect Postgres: %v\n", err)
    }

    // Checked two tables (user, address) created in database
    db.AutoMigrate(&User{}, &Address{})
    defer db.Close()

    u := User{
        Email: "some@one.com",
        Address: Address{
            Street:  "One street",
            City:    "Two city",
            Country: "Three country",
        },
    }

    fmt.Println(u)

    if err := db.Create(&u).Error; err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := db.Save(&u).Error; err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

After I run it with `go run main.go`:

```sh
{{0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC <nil>} some@one.com {{0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC <nil>} One street Two city Three country}}
```

It creates a new user but **does not create any address**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the foreign key in the `Address` assosation. For a has one relationship, a foreign key field must exist, the owned
will save the primary key of the model belongs to it into this field.

[Doc](http://gorm.io/docs/has_one.html)

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Email   string
    Address Address // One-To-One relationship (has one - use Address's UserID as foreign key)
}

type Address struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserID  uint
    Street  string
    City    string
    Country string
}
```